# List containing DTOS only prints out pointers

Tags: java, sql

Hey in the code below I store several SQL rows in this list. However when I print it, the only thing it displays is pointers. How do I get it to print out the rows of data so I can check if I am getting the correct info. Thanks guys!

```
List <UnitNotesDTO> list = unitNotesDao.getUnitNotes(TEST_UA_2); 
       System.out.println("start");
       System.out.println(list);
       System.out.println("end");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println` calls the object's `toString` method if it's not a `String`. By default, `toString` returns the pointer. You have to override the default implementation of `toString` in your `UnitNotesDTO`

Comment: I did that and its still printing out the pointers where i run the code

Comment: Could you add `UnitNotesDTO` to the question?